# Is "Harrison Wells" accurately pretending?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

A basic truth about season 1 of *The Flash* is that Doctor Harrison Wells is

> Eobard Thawne, a time traveler and the Reverse Flash, who stole the scientist's original body and is pretending to be paraplegic.

Being surrounded by smart people like Cisco and Caitlin, especially Caitlin who helps the team with medical things could potentially make this difficult.

Are his actions truly something that would fool someone as smart as Caitlin?

Comment: There are two subterfuges involved here. Are you asking about both of them?

Comment: I mean... they _did_ fool someone as smart as Caitlin, so I'm not sure exactly what better answer you're looking for...

Comment: @Politank-Z I think your edit is appropriate, thanks!

Comment: Note that Eobard Thawne is genius. He shares more or less the same intellect as Wells. He is well versed with everything of Speed Force. So, although he is not the _real_ Harrison Wells, it is really hard to distinguish him considering the level of deception he excels at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He fooled those who didn't get to meet the original Harrison Wells, specifically Barry, Caitlin, Ronnie and Cisco but in one episode Christina McGee, a scientist who *was* well acquainted with the real Wells, described him like this:

> He was such a kind man.
> Then everything changed after Tess died.
> They were gonna get married? I understand how grief can affect someone, but this was more than that.
> It was like, after that day, Harrison Wells became a completely different person.

<sup>*S1 E9 "All Star Team Up"*</sup>

In reference to the accident where Thawne killed both Harrison and his fiance and assumed Wells' identity. As for convincing Caitlin he was paralyzed, he had an apparent talent for deception (except for Detective West, but then his job is seeing through people).

Comment: In addition to Eobard Thawne's talent for deception, Caitlin is an innocent and sweet girl: she had no reason to suspect that the genius scientist she was idolising and working with was lying, and then do a second medical examination to check he was really paraplegic.

Comment: @Taladris No doubt Eobard falsified data about Caitlin's tests in order to convince her. His wheelchair deception had 9 months to set in before Barry wakes up so no wonder why she never really questions it later on.